# How can I pipe lines of a given file into a shell command?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a `req.txt` containing some package's name.

```sh
~ » cat req.txt                                      
code
heroku
postman
```

What I want to achieve is a one-line command like:

```sh
~ » cat req.txt | snap install "$1" --classic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) like so:

```
cat req.txt | xargs -I{} snap install --name={}
```

Here:
`-I{}` : Replace occurrences of string `{}` with the names read from STDIN.

Alternatively, use this Perl one-liner:

```
cat req.txt | perl -lne 'system "snap install --name=$_"; '
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`system` : Executes a system command.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: There's no need for the pipe: `< req.txt xargs ...`

Comment: That's great! +1 for the `xargs` addition! Anyhow, I'm struggling to understand why the download of the packages it's taking so long. It might be a connection issue but as the terminal is on hold and I can't see anything is hard to tell.

I tried to add a kind of log but without success:  `echo -e $(cat req.txt | xargs -I{} sudo snap install --classic {} )`; ` cat req.txt | xargs -I{} sudo snap install --classic {} | echo "$@"`; ` cat req.txt | xargs -I{} sudo snap install --classic {} | xargs `

None works.

Comment: @RaphaelSilva Sorry, not sure why the download is slow... Check your connection with https://www.speedtest.net/ or similar. Best asked as a separate question, perhaps not on SO but on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ .